# Ciclo repetitivo para crear filas y columnas en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy intentando hacer que cuando se coloque el numero de restricciones me muestre en filas y columnas de esta forma dependiendo del numero de variables que coloque el usuario ejemplo si coloco 3 variables y 4 restricciones debe apareces de esta forma x1:valor x2:valor y x3:valor (<=, >=, =) valor de la restricción. pero me sale así creo que necesito hacerlo con .grid porque no se si pueda usar for con .pack

Así es como me sale actualmente

[image: Así es como me sale actualmente]

Quiero que aparezca algo de esta forma

Así no importa tanto la apariencia quiero que solo sea funcional

[image: Así no importa tanto la apariencia quiero que solo sea funcional]

Este es el código que tengo

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from matplotlib import *
from pulp import *

# Crea la clase aplicacion la cual inicializa el programa
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None): # Inicializador del programa: llama todos los metodos creados y los ejecuta
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widget()
        self.text_boxes = [] # Lista para almacenar los cuadros de texto
        self.objective_label = None # Etiqueta de funcion objetivo
        self.label_restriccion = None # Etiqueta de restricciones
    
    # Este metodo crea todos los widget del programa
    def create_widget(self):
        Label(self, text="Ingresar numero de variables").pack()
    
        self.num_variables_entry = Entry(self, justify='center')
        self.num_variables_entry.pack()
    
        Label(self, text='Ingresar numero de restricciones').pack()
        self.num_restriction_entry = Entry(self, justify='center')
        self.num_restriction_entry.pack()
    
        Button(self, text="Aceptar", command=self.create_text_boxes).pack()
    
    def create_text_boxes(self):
        # Elimina los cuadros de texto anteriores
        for box in self.text_boxes:
            box.destroy()
        
        self.text_boxes.clear()  # Limpia la lista de cuadros de texto anteriores
    
        # Elimina el label "Función Objetivo" anterior si existe
        if self.objective_label:
            self.objective_label.destroy()
        
        #Elimina el label "Restricciones" anterior si existe
        if self.label_restriccion:
           self.label_restriccion.destroy()

        # Crea un nuevo label "Función Objetivo"
        self.objective_label = Label(self, text="Función Objetivo")
        self.objective_label.pack()
    
        num_boxes = int(self.num_variables_entry.get())  # Obtiene el número ingresado en la entrada de variables
        for i in range(num_boxes):
            entry = Entry(self)
            entry.pack()
            self.text_boxes.append(entry)  # Agrega los nuevos cuadros de texto a la lista
          
        self.label_restriccion = Label(self, text="Restricciones")
        self.label_restriccion.pack()
        
        num_boxes_r = int(self.num_restriction_entry.get()) # Obtiene el numero ingresado en la entrada de restricciones
        for i in range(num_boxes_r):
            entry_r = Entry(self)
            entry_r.pack()
            self.text_boxes.append(entry_r) # Agrega las nuevas restricciones a la lista
        
        # Elimina los botones anteriores si existen
        if hasattr(self, 'constraint_button'):
            self.constraint_button.destroy()
        if hasattr(self, 'solve_button'):
            self.solve_button.destroy()

        self.solve_button = Button(self, text="Resolver")
        self.solve_button.pack()
    
    def create_constraint(self):
        pass

    def solve(self):
        pass
        
root = Tk()
myapp = App(master=root)
myapp.master.title("Programación lineal")
myapp.mainloop()
```

Cualquier sugerencia lo apreciaría mucho soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo, cualquier optimización ya que no se si sea la forma correcta de emplear POO

Comment: En tu caso, el mejor método para alinear los elementos tanto horizontalmente como verticalmente es mediante el método grid. Con él podrás indicarle en que fila y columna quieres posicionar cada elemento y, si quieres que un elemento ocupe múltiples líneas, puedes hacerlo con rowspan, columnspan o sticky. Te dejo aquí un tutorial introductorio, fácil y corto para que empieces: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/